# How can I get the last section number to use at name?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am writing some notes containing many chapters and sections.
At the end of each section of this file I would like to insert a list of exercises with the following title:

```
Problems - Section x.y (x = chapter, y = section)

\begin{exercise}
blah blah blah
\end{exercise}
```

I could do this using a \label command like

```
     \section{NameSection}\label{secx.y}

bla bla bla


     Problems - Section \ref{secx.y}
        
        \begin{exercise}
        blah blah blah
        \end{exercise}
```

Is there any way to use some command like \lastchapter.section
or \current.chapther.section
instead of \ref{secx.y} ?

I'm using hyperlinks to.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathpazo, amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier, amssymb, ifthen,amsthm}
\usepackage[x11names, usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm ]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{eqparbox, ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=magenta}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newcounter{theeq} 
\counterwithin{theeq}{chapter}
\setcounter{theeq}{0}

\newcommand{\eq}{ 
    \
    
    \noindent 
    \refstepcounter{theeq}\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{theeq}}. }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\chapter{test1}
\lipsum[2]

\section{test1.1}\label{test1.1}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - Section \ref{test1.1}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx

\section{test1.2}\label{test1.2}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - Section \ref{test1.2}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx

\section{test1.3}\label{test1.3}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - Section \ref{test1.3}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx


\chapter{test2}
\lipsum[3]

\section{test2.1}\label{test2.1}

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - Section \ref{test2.1}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq \(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\)

\chapter{test3}

\section{test3.1}\label{test3.1}

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - Section \ref{test3.1}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you always put your Problems for Section X.Y *immediately* after Section X.Y? If yes, maybe you want to use `Problems - Section \thesection`?

Comment: There is an automatic hypertarget generated by `\section` for use in the TOC, which can be used by `\hyperlink{section.\thesection}{\thesection}` (no `\label` needed)

Comment: @Οὖτις thank you so much.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, it doesn't work for me. Could you explain me where I should insert the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in one run.  You can put almost anything into the text entry.

It may not always work for `section.\thesection`, depending on how `\thesection` is defined.  If you look in the aux file under `\contentsline` you will find the anchor name, `section.1.1` (for example).  That is what you need to reproduce for `\hyperlink`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathpazo, amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier, amssymb, ifthen,amsthm}
\usepackage[x11names, usenames,svgnames,dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm ]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{eqparbox, ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=magenta}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newcounter{theeq} 
\counterwithin{theeq}{chapter}
\setcounter{theeq}{0}

\newcommand{\eq}{ 
    \
    
    \noindent 
    \refstepcounter{theeq}\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{theeq}}. }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\chapter{test1}
\lipsum[2]

\section{test1.1}\label{test1.1}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - \hyperlink{section.\thesection}{Section \thesection}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx

\section{test1.2}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - \hyperlink{section.\thesection}{Section \thesection}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx

\section{test1.3}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - \hyperlink{section.\thesection}{Section \thesection}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx


\chapter{test2}
\lipsum[3]

\section{test2.1}

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - \hyperlink{section.\thesection}{Section \thesection}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq \(\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\)

\chapter{test3}

\section{test3.1}

\begin{center}
    \Large{Problems - \hyperlink{section.\thesection}{Section \thesection}}
\end{center}

\eq Let \(x \in R\)

\eq xx

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnKomylo